# TypeConversion Errors in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, aggregation, dsl

I'm doing a POC on whether Apache Camel can fit into my requirements as a request aggregator.

Let's say I have an existing system wherein I create users on two different services. So with Camel, I wish to aggregate these 2 steps into one single aggregate request. 
I have 2 different questions here.

- Is aggregator pattern the right way to do this? Meaning, at the end of it, I wish to fail my entire request if my call to first service fails for any reason.
- Second, [Please understand that I'm still a newbie to Camel and correct me] I tried implementing a basic flow where I want to do some transformation where I want to extract the first name from user's name from DemoUserRequest and pass it on to DemoUserMS1Request as below and call MS2 after that.

```
    @Component
public class DemoRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration()
                .component("servlet")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
                .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true");

        rest("/api/v1")
                .description("Create user flow")
                .id("create-user")
                .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .post("/user")
                .to("direct:createUser");

        from("direct:createUser")
                .log(" :: ${body} ")
                .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
                .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, DemoUserRequest.class)
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        Message message = exchange.getIn();
                        DemoUserRequest demoUserRequest = exchange.getIn(DemoUserRequest.class);
                        log.info("DemoUserRequest toString : " + demoUserRequest.toString());
                        DemoUserMS1Request demoUserMS1Request = new DemoUserMS1Request(demoUserRequest.getUserID(),
                                                                    demoUserRequest.getUserName(),
                                                                    demoUserRequest.getUserLanguage(),
                                                                    demoUserRequest.getUserName()
                                                                            .substring(0, demoUserRequest.getUserName().indexOf(' ')));
                        message.setBody(demoUserMS1Request);
                    }
                })
                .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, DemoUserMS1Request.class)
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
//                .toD("{{ms1.url}}/api/createUser");
                .to("stream:out");
    }
}
```

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
public class DemoUserRequest {
    private String userID;
    private String userName;
    private String userLanguage;
}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DemoUserMS1Request {
    private String userID;
    private String userName;
    private String userLanguage;
    private String userFirstName;
}
```

```
@Data
public class DemoUserMS2Request {
    private String userName;
}
```

I'm facing an issue when requesting

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8081/api/v1/user' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "userID" : "1",
    "userName" : "abc def",
    "userLanguage" : "EN"
}'
```

Camel throws errors like

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.unbxd.hagrid.routes.DemoRoute$1.process(DemoRoute.java:42)
```

[at the log.info line]
Is there any way I can cast my JSON request into my POJOs?

Comment: Hello, if i understood well, you want do bridge your rest call to 2 endpoints right? If this is the case, Camel doesn't need to be aware of your payload. You can declare onException in both "to" routes and only return a 200 if both succeed. Am i right?

Comment: Thanks for checking Rodrigo. I wanted to make Camel aware of the payload because I want some transformation to be done before calling other endpoints. Let's say I want to generate first name out of the username in DemoUserRequest and use it in DemoUserMS1Request.

Comment: Your POJOs, are they implementing serializable?

Comment: The data as I can see in the error is an Arraylist. You need to convert it into json before ummarshalling. Before your unmarshal, add `.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)` and see if it works for you.

Comment: @SneharghyaPathak I did marshal before unmarshalling as you've suggested now but it did not work as it is throwing NPE now indicating that the conversion is improper. Can you please suggest a way to fix this? [Edited the post to reflect my current code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have:

```
DemoUserRequest demoUserRequest = exchange.getIn(DemoUserRequest.class);
```

You should change to:

```
DemoUserRequest demoUserRequest = exchange.getIn().getBody(DemoUserRequest.class);
```

Comment: This worked because a typical exchange contains necessary headers for the route processor, along with the body. Thanks for the suggestion @rodrigocoelho